# Trying to retrieve JBPM process results from KIE Remote REST API

Tags: rest, jbpm, kie, remoteapi

I am trying to retrieve the result objects created by a business process via the KIE remote API:

```
if (baseURL != null) {
  System.out.println("[GlobalFlow]-Creating Engine");
  engine =     RemoteRuntimeEngineFactory.newRestBuilder().addUrl(baseURL).addUserName(user).add    Password(password)
  .addDeploymentId(deploymentId).addTimeout(10)
  .addExtraJaxbClasses(ClaimRequest.class, EvaluateLabClaimResponse.class,     SecondaryCodes.class,
  ResponseHeaderData.class, ResponseLineData.class, EvaluateLabClaim.class)
  .build();

KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

[create and store a bunch of params...]

ProcessInstance processInstance  = ksession.startProcess("defaultPackage.GlobalFlow", params);
```

}

Now I want to get the return values that were created by the remote JBPM process.  We have the objects sitting over there, all I need to do is get access to them.

How do I do that?

Comment: Following up post project.  They way we solved it was to use the REST API for JBPM and retrieve a process variable from the server that we placed the desired data into.  I can post the code if there is any interest.

Comment: Yes if you wouldn't mind! thank you